# Why do some people pronounce 'a' as 'u'?

Tags: pronunciation

I often hear English people pronounce 'a' as 'u' when using words like 'rather' and 'bravo'. Why is this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Is there any chance of linking an audio example?

Comment: Where are you from? Is it possible that you're using a dialect pronunciation of 'u' that is somehow close to the British broad 'a'? Normally, these two vowels are pretty far apart.

Comment: To those who don't believe Brits often do this, [here](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22I+druther%22&psj=1&oq=%22I+druther%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1713319l1718734l0l1719171l38l19l0l0l0l4l502l1995l9.2.1.0.1.1l14l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=57fad0bae3cb2180&biw=1305&bih=843) are 2770 written instances of **I druther**, which is clearly intended to reflect the actual pronunciaton of **I'd rather**. I do it myself sometimes, as a facetious "mock-yokel" usage (*druthers* is actually late 1800s slang).

Comment: perhaps you mean like [IPA ʌ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_unrounded_vowel) since "u" has at least 8 ways to be pronounced

Comment: I can't see how this is a very useful question to ask. Are you asking about the history of this particular nuance of pronunciation? Otherwise surely the answer is simply "they pronounce it that way because that happens to be their particular regional variant".

Comment: @Cass73 Perhaps you can identify where those speakers are from? It appears that they may be from the north of England (like me!) so the following link which highlights vowel differences between 'standard' and northern English may be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_English

Comment: 'Why' questions are difficult to answer. The form of a reason here might something like 'people from the north of England often say X instead of Y because of <some historical invasion/social thing from another linguistic community>'. Otherwise, reasons are usually 'because they changed'. Do you know if the speakers who say 'a' that way come from a particular region/kind of English speaker?

Answer (score 1):

After having read the comments above I'm going to take a shot in the dark and assume that @Cass73 is referring to the way that some British accents may pronounce an 'a' in a similar manner as the 'u' in crumb.

The short answer, as @Mitch said in the comments is that questions like these are difficult, if not impossible, to answer definitively. It's the way that people from a given region pronounce these words in this way. Whether they changed, or people outside that region changed, or everyone changed from the way the words were pronounced canonically 200 years ago is something you would need a linguistic historian to answer.